# Formly Reset the Errors on Focus Out for Prime Input Mask

Tags: angular, angular-formly, ngx-formly

Formly should retain error instead of nullifying the errors for inputmask.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ljcdzn-3r3fwu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Finput-mask.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

By default, I have set the invalid error to true on model changes to the inputMask field and input field. When we enter the value and focus out, the error bound to the inputMask is vanishing, whereas for the input field, it is retaining the error .

Comment: why do you want to retain the error, please share exactly what you are trying to achieve, because you are doing `setErrors` you are getting these issues, you need to ask the main question, why you want to do this!

Comment: Hi, Naren Murali, We are having a scenario where the input mask is valid only if the user enters up to 5 or 9 digits; if it fails, then we will be displaying the error message using setErrors. Imagine that I have entered seven digits and an error is displayed. If I enter backspace, inputMask is refreshing the errors, so the error message is not retained. This case apparently works for the "input" type but not the "input mask."